# CLion filesystem linker problem even with -lstdc++fs

Tags: linker, filesystems, c++17, clion

I've tried to use `<filesystem>` in my CLion project on Fedora 29 environment.
When compiling directly from terminal it works smoothly, but when i try to compile from CLion there is a Linker issue about filesystem. I'm not shure what else I can do. Any suggestions?

- g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)
- clang version 7.0.1
  (Fedora 7.0.1-6.fc29)

Here is what i have already tried:

I've added  the flag -lstdc++fs:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -lstdc++fs)
```

but i didn't worked. I've verified if this flag is in use by:

```
set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )
```

and it seems it is:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++    -lstdc++fs -g   -std=gnu++17 -o 
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -c 
/home/patryk/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
/home/patryk/clion-2018.3.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -E 
cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++  -lstdc++fs -g   CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o  -o 
untitled 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: in function 
`std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path<char [2], 
std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>(char const (&) [2], 
std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:184: undefined reference to 
`std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried also to use clang compiler with exact same results.

```
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::path p("D");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMake` use `target_link_libraries` to add `-l` linker flags.

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable stdc++fs)
```

Why `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -lstdc++fs)` not working: `-l` option must be set **after** your source or object file.

```sh
c++ -lstdc++fs some_object.o -o executable # not working
c++ some_object.o -o executable -lstdc++fs # should work
```